# Flutter Build Fails with HMS Integration: com.huawei.agconnectclouddb.objecttypes Package Not Found

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, huawei-mobile-services

I am working on integrating Huawei Mobile Services (HMS) into my existing Flutter application by following the official [documentation](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-get-started-flutter-0000001057642285).

Here is what I have done so far:

1. I have created a project in AppGallery Connect and set up an Android app.
2. Downloaded the agconnect-services.json configuration file and placed it in the android/app directory.

   [image]
3. Added the necessary Gradle configurations to the project-level build.gradle and the app-level build.gradle.

android level build.gradle:

```
allprojects { 
            repositories { 
                google() 
                jcenter() 
                // Add the following line:
                maven {url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/'} 
            } 
        }

buildscript { 
            repositories { 
                google() 
                jcenter() 
                // Add the following line:
                maven {url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/'} 
            } 
 }
//buildscript > dependencies
buildscript { 
            dependencies { 
             // Add the following line:
             classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.9.0.300'
            } 
}
```

app-level build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.huawei.agconnect'
```

4. Included the HMS dependencies agconnect_crash and agconnect_clouddb in my pubspec.yaml:

   [image: pubspec.yaml]
5. Ran 'flutter pub get' to fetch packages.

But when I try to run the application, the build fails with the following errors:

```
PS C:\Users\User\hulatech_teacher_app> flutter run    
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\agconnect_clouddb-1.9.0+300\android\src\main\java\com\huawei\agconnectclouddb\modules\AGCCloudDBModule.java:29: error: package com.huawei.agconnectclouddb.objecttypes does not exist
import com.huawei.agconnectclouddb.objecttypes.ObjectTypeInfoHelper;
                                              ^
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\agconnect_clouddb-1.9.0+300\android\src\main\java\com\huawei\agconnectclouddb\utils\AGCCloudDBUtil.java:8: error: package com.huawei.agconnectclouddb.objecttypes does not exist
import com.huawei.agconnectclouddb.objecttypes.ObjectTypeInfoHelper;
                                              ^
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\agconnect_clouddb-1.9.0+300\android\src\main\java\com\huawei\agconnectclouddb\modules\AGCCloudDBModule.java:77: error: cannot find symbol
            AGConnectCloudDB.getInstance().createObjectType(ObjectTypeInfoHelper.getObjectTypeInfo());
                                                            ^
  symbol:   variable ObjectTypeInfoHelper
  location: class AGCCloudDBModule
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\agconnect_clouddb-1.9.0+300\android\src\main\java\com\huawei\agconnectclouddb\utils\AGCCloudDBUtil.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
        for (Class<? extends CloudDBZoneObject> clazz : ObjectTypeInfoHelper.getObjectTypeInfo().getObjectTypes()) {
                                                        ^
  symbol:   variable ObjectTypeInfoHelper
  location: class AGCCloudDBUtil
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
4 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':agconnect_clouddb:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 52s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             53,7s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

HMS dependencies versions provided by the official documentation were out of date, so I checked the pub.dev and updated the versions. I was expecting the app to build successfully and run in debug mode on my emulator/device.

What could be causing these errors, and how can I resolve them?